# setting margin of a TableRow issue

Tags: java, android

I have the following code, which tries to set the margin:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
                    TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
                          new TableLayout.LayoutParams
                          (TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                          int leftMargin=20;
                          int topMargin=50;
                          int rightMargin=0;
                          int bottomMargin=50;

                         tableRowParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
                         tr.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

 TextView name = new TextView(this);
                          name.setText(Html.fromHtml(venues.get(j).name + "<br><br>" + venues.get(j).getFullAddress()));
```

However this doesn't set the margin. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Edit. Whoops, my bad, TableLayout.LayoutParams is fine. Use TableRow.LayoutParams on the children of the TableRow.

I just ran this code (which is, for the most part, your code) and the margin sets correctly

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
TableLayout.LayoutParams tableRowParams=
    new TableLayout.LayoutParams
    (TableLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    int leftMargin=100;
    int topMargin=50;
    int rightMargin=0;
    int bottomMargin=50;

    tableRowParams.setMargins(leftMargin, topMargin, rightMargin, bottomMargin);
      tr.setLayoutParams(tableRowParams);

    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("EXAMPLE ROW");
    TableRow.LayoutParams textParams = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(textParams);
    tr.addView(tv);

    tlayout.addView(tr);
```

Answer (score -1):

isn't it like so?

```
   TableRow tr = new TableRow(Activity.this)
```

And I thik you'll nee a table for that row too.

Why not go for XML ?

```
<TableRow
 android:id="@+id/tr1"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</TableRow>
```

Comment: You can inflate this row to your layout. For instance